# How can I delete all elements from a list from a particular elemen in the list?

Tags: python, list

i have a list like below:

```
myList = [3, 5, 7, 2, 100, 76]
```

I want to delete all the elements from the list starting with the element 2, i.e., after deletion the list should like this:

```
myList = [3, 5, 7]
```

How can I do that? There's no duplicate elements in the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean something like this

```
>>> myList = [3, 5, 7, 2, 100, 76]
>>> myList.index(2)
3
>>> myList[:myList.index(2)]
[3, 5, 7]
>>>
```